# vim incremental command history search

Tags: search, command-history

In bash you can easily search the current history entries by hitting `<C-r>` or `<C-s>`. This search feature is incremental, and once you hit return, you get a bash prompt auto-filled with the closest match in your history. I know if I want to search for a vim command I can hit `q:` and then search with `/`. However, I find this slow. Tab completion somewhat alleviates the tedium of searching for command, but is not quite satisfactory. Does vim have a similar feature?

Comment: Like you stated, you could open up the search command window using `q:` and then search that window with `/`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware that this is possible. The only thing I know is, that Vim uses the already typed characters to filter the history.

If you previously executed:

```
:%s/This/That/g
```

and you want to get this command again, you do

```
:%s/T<up>
```

This will get only commands that start with `%s/T` from the history.

See [`:help c_Up`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_Up) for more details.

Comment: Yes, up arrow is the closest to what you get with Ctrl-R in bash. It's not exactly the same, but I'd say it's close enough. Full search on `q:` is the next step after that.

Comment: Everything is possible with enough plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fuzzy searching using FZF(as I do). Check https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim  .

```
function! GetCommands()
let lines=[]
let nu=histnr("cmd")
for i in range(1,nu)
    let lines+=[histget("cmd",i)]
endfor
return lines
endfunction

function! HandleCommand(item)
    call feedkeys("q:")
    call feedkeys("G?\\V".escape(a:item,'\/?')."\<CR>")
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-a>c :call fzf#run({'source': GetCommands(),'sink': function('HandleCommand'),'options': '-m'} )<CR>
```

When I press `<c-a>c` , it displays me a fuzzy search for command. Then, when I press enter, it goes to the command in the command window. If I press another enter it executes. I can also edit the command.

You may also want to do

```
set history=10000
nnoremap <silent> <C-a><C-a> <C-a>
```

to save longer command history, and the functionality of `<c-a>`.